# Make a sum of sum of lists in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, sum

This is my whole code for a work in progress:

```
 nList = [[[0,0,4287320],[10423234600,0,63248900]],\
[],\
[[132447000,10432900,134820]],\
[[0,0,0],[3002340,4324000,303420],[3003420,40023420,720424],[0,0,102432420]],\
[[132432450,0,0],[10034220,0,36432230], [400432240,40243200,6432260],[4000423, 40243200, 964234240],[12342400,0,132342420]]]
```

Decoding the list:
nList has multiple traces with trace1 having two points, trace2 having no points, trace3 having 1 point and so one. each point in the trace is made up of three elements [x co-ordinate, y co-ordinate, time.

At the end of this whole code, I need to print the `sum(sum(lengthList))`, and this formula obviously doesn't work. Problem is, I have also tried `print map(sum(sum, lengthList))`, `print sum(sum(lengthList))` and none of them have worked. It also has to be a function and not just a print as the nList needs to work for multiple lists of a similar nature. Thanks for the help!

Comment: This should help you from the "float object not iterable" error !  

    `sum([sum(float(x) for x in lengthList)])`

Good Luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made two modifications.Change length_list outside the function.

```
length_list=[]
def lengths(trace):

sum_of_all_lengths=[]
for i in range(0,len(trace)-1):
    length=calculateLength(trace[i][0], trace[i][1], trace[i+1][0], trace[i+1][1])
    length_list.append(length)
return length_list
```

at the end you can have this

```
print sum(length_list)
```

Answer (score 2):

This should help you from the "float object not iterable" error !

**Edit:**

Declare the below, above the forloop

> lengthList=[]

and in the last else part of the for loop

> lengthList.append(sum(float(x) for x in lengths(trace)))

Out side the for loop

> print [sum(float(x) for x in lengthList)]

Good Luck!

Comment: Hey,  
  I've tried this & it works!

Regards.

p.s.: You can work it out on the idle & report back if it throws an error. For me, it worked just fine.

Comment: Hi @AlekhyaVemavarapu. I tried this and it gave me sum(lengthLists) outputs. Not sum of the sum(lengthLists).

Comment: May I know what you exactly require ? Cuz I did not really get your question, So worked on the error that u've mentioned.

Regards.

Comment: I need the output that soon produced: 22436.59108938537. The sum(sum(lengthList)).

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html):

```
sum([sum(x) for x in lengthList])
```

This would sum the points values in lengthList, and then return the sum of those sums.

Or as @soon pointed out, a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators):

```
sum(sum(x) for x in lengthList)
```

Although if you want to use any list methods, you should use the list comprehension.

Comment: No reason for list comprehension - just use generator like this `sum(sum(x) for x in [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])` or [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) function.

Comment: @Tui Popenoe I keep getting the error 'float' object is not iterable. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: Are all your points in lengthList defined as lists/tuples? Or are single values represented with floats (what sounds like is going on)

Comment: Why would you need list methods? Sum would return an int/float.

Comment: If you wanted to modify a sublist before summing the sublists.

Comment: All values in lengthList are distances between points in each trace, @TuiPopenoe. That is, distance between trace1point1 and trace1point2 is length 1000, trace4point1=[0,0,0] and trace4point2=[3000,4000,300] is length (3000^2+4000^2)^0.5=5000.00 and so on. so, sum of lengthList[3]= sum of lengths of trace4 would be 10,000.

Answer (score 1):

just take a list `lengthList = []` and enter element by  [extend](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_extend.htm)

you can change simple in your code in last `for loop`

```
lengthList = []
for i in range(len(traceList)):
    trace=traceList[i]
    if len(trace)==0:
        print "Trace {0} has no points!".format(i)
    elif len(trace)==1:
        print "Trace {0} consists of a single point.".format(i)
    else:
        #lengthList=lengths(trace)            
        lengthList.extend(lengths(trace))

print sum(lengthList)
```

Output

```
Trace 1 has no points!
Trace 2 consists of a single point.
22436.5910894
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to calculate the total length of all traces, you should firstly calculate the lengths of all traces:

```
In [9]: lengths_of_all_traces = map(lengths, (trace for trace in traceList if len(trace) > 1))

In [10]: lengths_of_all_traces
Out[10]: [[1000.0], [5000.0, 0.0, 5000.0], [850.0, 5000.0, 0.0, 5586.591089385369]]
```

As you can see, we skip traces with zero or one points.

The next step is calculating the total length. You could just pass generator expression to `sum` function:

```
In [11]: total_length = sum(sum(t) for t in lengths_of_all_traces)

In [12]: total_length
Out[12]: 22436.59108938537
```

Actually, you could remove the condition `if len(trace) > 1`, since `sum` works with empty lists pretty well:

```
In [13]: lengths_of_all_traces = map(lengths, traceList)

In [14]: lengths_of_all_traces
Out[14]: 
[[1000.0],
 [],
 [],
 [5000.0, 0.0, 5000.0],
 [850.0, 5000.0, 0.0, 5586.591089385369]]

In [15]: total_length = sum(sum(t) for t in lengths_of_all_traces)

In [16]: total_length
Out[16]: 22436.59108938537
```

You could also use [`imap`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.imap) function (which returns iterator) instead of `map` (which returns `list`) for saving memory.

Comment: I need the lengths stored in the form I have because I use individual trace lengths for much more complex functions later on. Unfortunately, I can't change the composition of my current code without jeopardizing the rest. I strongly simplified my original code to only show part I was stuck on.